# Error Installing package from github with devtools

Tags: r, devtools

Trying to install the lego package from Github on Windows in R version 3.1.1 gives the following error:

```
Error in set(new) : cannot change working directory.
```

I can verify that Rtools in installed fine and `find_rtools()` returns TRUE. The debug information indicates it find it in the right location.

Comment: I think this is highly related.  Try and let us know: https://github.com/trinker/reports/issues/51

Comment: Does the error message give any other clues, like what function or file called "set"? `devtools` doesn't have a `set` function so don't blame it yet. Do any other packages install okay?

Comment: I tried calling `traceback` but id didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by wrong command.
The standard command for change working director is `setwd(new)`

Comment: I understand that, I am not calling the set command. It is happening somewhere in devtools.